# Term joins not working on Kibana map with French departments

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, geojson

I am currently trying to create a Map on Kibana to display data on a map of France, but when I try to join the geo data's index with my data index using the *département* codes it simply does not work.

In "Terms joins", when I only provide as a left source and field the GeoJson index and the "dep" field (which regroups *départements* by code), it does display the *départements* as expected. Once I try to join it with, as a left source and field, my other index and the "num_dept" field (which also regroups *départements* codes), it displays neither *départements* nor data - using the "num_dept.keywork" field makes no difference either.

I believe I have ensured that both fields are the same type and have the same values: they are both set as `{ "fielddata": true, "type": "text" }`. I updated them both using these parameters:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "num_dept": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true,
      "fields": { "raw": { "type": "keyword" } } 
    }
  }
}
```

The only difference I've found is that "num_dept" is marked as aggregatable in the index pattern, and "dep" is not. I am not sure if this is important?

The values for "dep" from the GeoJSON index returns:

```json
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 101,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "langs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "01",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "02",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "03",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "04",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "05",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "06",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "07",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "08",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "09",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "10",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "11",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "12",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "13",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "14",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "15",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "16",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "17",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "18",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "19",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "21",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "22",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "23",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "24",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "25",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "26",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "27",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "28",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "29",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "2a",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "2b",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "30",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "31",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "32",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "33",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "34",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "35",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "36",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "37",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "38",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "39",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "40",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "41",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "42",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "43",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "44",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "45",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "46",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "47",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "48",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "49",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "50",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "51",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "52",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "53",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "54",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "55",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "56",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "57",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "58",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "59",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "60",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "61",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "62",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "63",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "64",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "65",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "66",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "67",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "68",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "69",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "70",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "71",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "72",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "73",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "74",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "75",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "76",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "77",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "78",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "79",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "80",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "81",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "82",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "83",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "84",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "85",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "86",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "87",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "88",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "89",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "90",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "91",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "92",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "93",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "94",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "95",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "971",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "972",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "973",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "974",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "976",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The values for "num_dept" from the other index:

```json
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 7494,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "langs" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "01",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "02",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "03",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "04",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "05",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "06",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "07",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "08",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "09",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "10",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "11",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "12",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "13",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "14",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "15",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "16",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "17",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "18",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "19",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "21",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "22",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "23",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "24",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "25",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "26",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "27",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "28",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "29",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "2a",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "2b",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "30",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "31",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "32",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "33",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "34",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "35",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "36",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "37",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "38",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "39",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "40",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "41",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "42",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "43",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "44",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "45",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "46",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "47",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "48",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "49",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "50",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "51",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "52",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "53",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "54",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "55",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "56",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "57",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "58",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "59",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "60",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "61",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "62",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "63",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "64",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "65",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "66",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "67",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "68",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "69",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "70",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "71",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "72",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "73",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "74",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "75",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "76",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "77",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "78",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "79",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "80",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "81",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "82",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "83",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "84",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "85",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "86",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "87",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "88",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "89",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "90",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "91",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "92",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "93",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "94",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "95",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "972",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "974",
          "doc_count" : 75
        },
        {
          "key" : "971",
          "doc_count" : 74
        },
        {
          "key" : "973",
          "doc_count" : 69
        },
        {
          "key" : "976",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I am using GeoJSON from [data.gouv.fr](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/contours-des-communes-de-france-simplifie-avec-regions-et-departement-doutre-mer-rapproches/), not Elastic's French *départements* GeoJSON data because it does not cover overseas *départements* (DOM).

Comment: Which elasticsearch version is it?

Comment: The version is 7.4.2.

Comment: Ha! I asked because I'm currently seeing an issue with 7.13.x but was working well with 7.11.x.

Comment: Could you try with a type keyword instead of text?

Comment: I think both of them are already keywords? I have edited the question to indicate what parameters I gave these fields.

Comment: Could you try on `num_dept.raw` instead?

Comment: `num_dept.keywork` or `num_dept.keyword` (without the typo) does not match the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think that version 7.13.2 which has just been released yesterday should fix the issue hopefully.